# When to use Angular with Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a pretty basic question.

Consider a CRUD web application built on Django. You have templates that render data. Those templates might have forms where you submit data to the backend, and that might reload the page to display changes. Sometime, you can make those requests over AJAX, for example when you need to update data on the UI. You can also submit forms with AJAX and update the HTML with it.

On the other hand you have single page applications. You serve a static file, and there is no reload of pages. You have data that comes from an API and populates some front-end template.

What are some guidelines for when to use what? Not in a mutually exclusive way, but within one Django project, what are some reasons/considerations to use a Django template/forms/AJAX approach and when to use Angular?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is how "interactive" you want the client-side to be.

I am in the process of converting an existing Django app to use Angular (and django-rest-framework).  The app was highly interactive and relied on a lot of custom JQuery to get various widgets working just right.  JQuery's constant looping through the DOM made it pretty slow.  I am finding that using Angular instead of JQuery is much faster.

So if you have a lot of complexity in the front-end, I would recommend Angular.